# how to push/present view controller while unity is running

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine

I need to develop swift app that is using Unity as part of it. While the unity is running, The users need to be able to open new view. However, whenever I push or present a new view after the unity opened up, It never seems to be able to present on top of unity. I can see that the new view controller is opened up as it is calling restAPI when that page is loaded, but it isn't showing the screen to the user.

I am using UnityBridge class for my unity which I found online. I made buttons on top of the screen to be able to press to open new view. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thank you